# How to deploy Java servlet to server

Tags: java, git, amazon-web-services, servlets, deployment

I asked someone to develop a web application with Java servlet.

The person compiles it on the local PC when deploying to the server,
I was working on uploading the completed .war file to the server.

It was a very innovative way for me who had experience of only Rails and PHP.
In the Java servlet, is it general to deploy like this?

On the other hand, after logging in to the server and pulling the source with Git,
Is it impossible to compile and deploy on the server?

I would like to ask your opinion and experience of many people.
Thank you.

Comment: why all the unrelated tags? do you think git or amazon-web-services have any influence on your situation?

Comment: I think that those who have work experience with AWS have a lot of knowledge and can use Java servlet as well.

Comment: servlets are an ancient technology. either way, if the source in git is complete, either yes, you can build and deploy, or the source code is buggy. You may have to have some local configuration, but that shouldn't be all that much work

Comment: It is still unclear what is your question. There are multiple ways how to deploy the application. And it is not necessary feasible to compile and build an app on the server (possibly having some private repositories or settings).

Answer (score -1):

There are many options when it comes to building and deploying Java webapps on AWS, depending on what tooling you prefer, how you prefer to deploy apps, what level of automation you want, and more.

Please see [Deploying Java Web Applications](https://aws.amazon.com/answers/web-applications/aws-web-app-deployment-java/)